# How to make a POST request with httpclient in net core and javascript

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, fetch, dotnet-httpclient

Im having a very bad time triying to figure out this problem, I have a web API made in net core 6 with Entity Framework, in this web api I have to consume a third party API. If a try to make a POST request directly the Swagger UI it works perfectly:
[POST in Swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7Ok3.png)
HOWEVER, if i made a post request in javascript using fetch it return a 400 error, that to be honest doesn't say much:
[400 error response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU6du.png)
I know there is no missing data in my post request, I checked a lot, in fact there is no field call "data".

**Here is the code to make a fetch in the frontend:**

```
return fetch(apiURL, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
    .then(response => response.json())
```

**Here is the post method in net core**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<string> PostProductAsync(string data)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.PostAsync(path, new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return json;
    }
```

I'm a bit confused. What could i be doing wrong.

**UPDATE**

I followed each instruction in the answers section, and I can say that it makes a lot of sense to put [FromBody] in the POST method since in the fetch method I am sending the data in the body.
However this led me to a new parsing error: [parsing error after POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr6yD.png)

I have been searching in other forums about this error, it seems that what is recommended in this case is to make a class [Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path '', line 1, position 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57678571/unexpected-character-encountered-while-parsing-value-path-line-1-positio)

Now, the problem that i have with this approach its that i have quite a big json to post, witch means that i will have to create a lot of classes to make this possible. Its there any way to this without creating a class?

So far i tried the following changes in the POST method:

**Adding [FromBody]**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<string> PostProductAsync([FromBody] string data)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.PostAsync(path, new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return json;
    }
```

This one leads to the parsing error mentioned before.

**Adding [FromBody] and changing string to object**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<string> PostProductAsync([FromBody] object data)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.PostAsync(path, new StringContent(data.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return json;
    }
```

This one leads to a non valid JSON [is not a valid JSON error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uf2K.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your Swagger UI is sending your data as a `Query` parameter, but you are trying to post it through `body` in your fetch. They are two different methods of post. I recommend you use `body` only.

Change your controller method to use the `[FromBody]` parameter attribute:
`PostProductAsync([FromBody] string data)`

More information from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody

Defaults for a **string**, in your case:

> If the parameter is a "simple" type, Web API tries to get the value from the URI. Simple types include the .NET primitive types (int, bool, double, and so forth), plus TimeSpan, DateTime, Guid, decimal, and **string**, plus any type with a type converter that can convert from a string. (More about type converters later.)

So the default behavior is what Swagger is currently using.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to pass json type data,you need to use `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` in fetch,and then use `[FromBody]`in action.

fetch:

```
return fetch(apiURL, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
    .then(response => response.json())
```

action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<string> PostProductAsync([FromBody]string data)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.PostAsync(path, new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return json;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can bind model in two ways.

### Simple type model binding approach

Since you are accepting  simple type **string** value in controller, you can use `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` in `fetch` and you can pass parameter data in the URL as following:

At fetch:

```
let apiURL = `https://localhos:8080/Test/data`;

return fetch(apiURL, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: null
}).then(response => response.json())
```

### Complex type model binding approach

Let's assume you're now posting complex object type data. To post data from request body `Content-Type` should be `application/json`. And add `[FromBody]` in the action to define the location to get data from request. Here's the example code snippet.

At fetch:

```
return fetch(apiURL, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
}).then(response => response.json())
```

At controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<string> PostProductAsync([FromBody]string data)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.PostAsync(path, new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return json;
    }
```

On a side note, please avoid using `text/plain` as `Content-Type` to avoid [security issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075570/what-are-the-potential-issues-of-using-text-plain-as-the-content-type-for-xml-ov).
Hope this helps you and here's for your further reference [for model binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#simple-types-1).